# Should a bass pattern in a harmony exercise be carried through the entire exercise?

Tags: voice-leading

In this exercise the bass pattern is indicated below the melody in bar 2 and 3 but should this pattern be carried through the entire exercise or should all other notes be harmonised note for note (except for exceptions marked with asterix)?

[image]

Comment: We probably can’t answer this question. The chapter preceding the homework assignment would ideally explain how to do the homework. Also your teacher is the best person to clarify what they expect from your homework. Also it might be clearer to call that a “harmonic rhythm” and not a “bass pattern”. A pattern is sometimes a complete line of music with notes and rhythms. What’s indicated here is just a rhythm for the accompaniment.

Comment: My teacher? At the moment the only person that could be is you :) I can assure you that nothing in the preceding chapter would clarify this. I can say that normally all my harmony exercises in the textbook has note for note harmonisations so based on that I guess the most I could ask you is for your interpretation on how to harmonize this.

Comment: I think what we’ve seen so far and other screenshots from this book is that you are mostly left free to your own devices, and that it just adds small clues to guide you where necessary. I think you can do whatever you want in the  other measures.

Comment: Maybe you could look for a better book

Comment: @Andy your are right but you soon find that the clues are usually enough to guide you it is just sometimes I get stuck and it is good to get a fresh opinion

Comment: @Todd that is highly unlikely, I have several and this is the one that I like most

Answer (score 1):

The positions of the "don't harmonize" asterisks imply that the half note-quarter note-half note tied to 8th note-8th note pattern does not extend to those measures. Note that, if you extend the pattern to those measures by consecutively placing pattern units next to each other, those notes with asterisks naturally will not be re-harmonized. The exercise has to specially reinforce that those notes should not be (re-)harmonized: this implies that the natural temptation to harmonize them is there in the first place.

Comment: So then all the notes after that point do need to be harmonized note for note? Even the triplets? else why would they specify that those 16th notes marked with an asterix shouldnt be harmonized unless like you say the temptationis to harmonize them note for note.

Comment: @armani - I would hazard a guess that not all the melody after that point needs to be harmonized note for note - my natural guess for the 2nd measure with an asterisk is to harmonize it with 3 quarter notes in the bass - but the temptation will always be there if you know you don't need to follow the pattern, and a 2 quarter notes-into-2 8th notes bassline for that measure is also pretty tempting.